# How can I make my iframe fit the whole section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

The problem I'm having is located at http://fourbetpoker.com/play/index.html

If you click on either "Poker" or "Dice", you'll see that my iframe has space around it (easier to see on the dicing tab). Can anyone tell me why, and potential fixes? I've been messing with the code for well over an hour and I have no idea what's wrong with it. I'm a newbie when it comes to Bootstrap/CSS. Thanks!

Comment: why you are using iframe inside ul like this:                           <ul><div class="col-md-12">
        <iframe src="http://23.92.61.79:8087/" id="info" class="iframe" name='info' width="100%" height="92%" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" align="left"></iframe>
    </div>   </ul> </div>

Comment: can you share a pic of the issue you are facing, its difficult to understand from that link.?

Comment: @Kiran: I took that out. I've been trying so many different things, couldn't tell ya why it was there.

@G: http://gyazo.com/c4ec84b60084c9e21a51ae04b8da02d4 I want to get rid of that extra black on top.

Answer (score 0):

When I click Dice tab, I saw lot of empty space around for the content. It is coming because of the following class available in global.css file. Margin applied around the form.

```
  #loginContent #loginHeadlineContainer
  {
    margin:100px 100px 0 100px;
  }
```

If you don't want apply any margin then reduce it in the class. By Simple make it zero.

```
 #loginContent #loginHeadlineContainer
 {
   margin:0;
 }
```

Comment: I don't believe any properties are inherited from global.css- that css sheet is used for my forum software.

Comment: i have checked in developer tool(chrome) and it render that properties. I just removed that properties and it removes the empty areas.